# PDE question, weak derivative equals 0 then it's constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega$ is open, bounded, with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some $p\in(1,\infty)$.

Suppose $Du=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$. Prove that $u$ is a constant a.e. in $\Omega$.

Comment: Did you try using the mollifier?

Comment: I try to construct a function $\phi \in C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ such that $\int_\Omega u\phi_x\,dx \neq 0$

Comment: But why did that imply $u$ constant?

Comment: Yes, I try to use. But when I use the mollifier, it will contribute to the integration. By the way, could you give me the reference? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edit it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG I prove a dim=1 version  that I assume $\Omega=(a,b)$,

Then $\forall\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ we have $\int_a^b u\phi^{'}=0$.

pick $\alpha\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) \int_a^b\alpha=1$, this is always existed. Then we consider $\psi-\alpha\int_a^b\psi\in C_c^{\infty}$ which have $\int_a^b(\psi-\alpha\int_a^b\psi)dx =0$ then we can get its primitive $\lambda\in C_c^{\infty}$ $ \lambda^{'}=\psi-\alpha\int_a^b\psi$, so$0=\int_a^b u\lambda^{'}=\int_a^b u(\psi-\alpha\int_a^b\psi)=\int_a^b u\psi dx-(\int_a^b\psi dx)\int_a^b \alpha udx=\int_a^b (u-\int_a^b \alpha udx)\psi dx $ hold for $\forall\psi\in C_c^{\infty}$ so $u\equiv\int_a^b \alpha udx $a.e. which is constant.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. But could you share your thoughts about this question? I mean how you can come up with this idea? Could you say something about your intuition?

Comment: And I don't understand this: which have $\int_a^b(\psi-\alpha\int_a^b\psi)dx =0$ then we can get its primitive $\lambda\in C_c^{\infty}$

Comment: It is a basic question about weak derivatives, actually we can do it better from this: $u\in W^{1,p}$ iff u is absolutely continuous and $u^{'}\in L^p$.

Comment: Reference! Reference! And the question in the second comment...

Comment: You can let $\lambda=\int_a^x ....dy$ then it is smooth and equal to 0 on the boundary.

Comment: You can find something useful in Brezis's book